# Is it possible to remove tags created by mistake?

Tags: support

While I was trying add the tag [broken-code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-code) to a question, I inadvertently created a new tag [brok](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brok) by clumsy typing. I would like to delete that useless tag, but don't see any way to do it. It there a way, or do I have to leave it to wither away from disuse?

Answer (score 3):

Using the moderator tag merge tool I merged this tag with [broken-code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-code).
That appears to have taken care of it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your taking the time to relieve my embarrassment

Comment: @m_goldberg and Mr.Wizard, "deleting" a tag is as simple as just removing it from all questions that currently have it. So in the case of typos like the above, just correcting it will do. Unused tags will simply be pruned at the end of the day (i.e., won't be in autocomplete suggestions). Don't be fooled by the genuine looking page with 0 questions that you see when you visit the typo tag's link. By default every tag page (whether existing or not) is styled that way... [see for yourself](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-goldberg-made-a-typo) :)

Comment: @rm-rf. Thanks for the additional information. I indeed was fooled by "0 questions" page you mention.

Comment: @m_goldberg I was wondering what exactly [tag:broken-code] is used for? Is it because the poster's code is syntactically incorrect or is it because it does not do what s/he expects? There is no wiki to help me to decide, and the [first example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32632/difference-in-two-codes) that pops up seems to have correct syntax.

Comment: @IstvánZachar the person posting the question may not know why the code doesn't work.  Have you seen [my question that originated it?](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1070/121)

Comment: @IstvánZachar. The question I tagged with [tag:broken-code] was [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31361/3066). The OP explicitly said it evaluated but that it wasn't giving the correct result.

Comment: Thanks Mr.W, I missed that thread. @m_goldberg I understand now the purpose! Are you waiting for some trend/policy to emerge or momentum gained before editing the tag wiki? I proposed a first version, please feel free to modify it!

Comment: @IstvánZachar. Can't modify it. Seems I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: @m_goldberg Can't modify what?  A tag wiki?  You should have plenty of reputation for that.  What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @István I guess I was.  I appreciate your taking part.

Comment: @István Looking at your wiki proposal I think it would be better if we do not exclude syntax errors.  I think I understand your intention, but there are cases that are difficult to understand; a question can still be closed as "simple mistake" if it is such.

Comment: @Mr.W Sure, it's fine by me. The point is to have a common baseline for everyone to see.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Couldn't edit/modify a tag wiki undergoing review. Could only vote to accept or reject.